# Capability of Relay

Tags: relay

I'm looking into the following relay:

https://www.distrelec.ch/Web/Downloads/ta/_e/bhS66_data_e.pdf

I will use this relay in the NC configuration and it needs to open 6A @ 12VDC but it needs to be able to close 30A under 54VDC. From the datasheet, the breaking capacity is 25A @ < 30VDC, so this should be fine, but what about closing again? Can I close like specified in the NO raiting (30A @ 250VAC) or how is this specified?

Comment: I doubt it will survive more than a few cycles. Get a DC rated relay? Use an SSR instead?

Comment: What kind of load is the relay driving?  Resistive, inductive?  Usually the damage or wearing of the relay contacts occur when the contacts open because of the unavoidable (unless special circuit design techniques are employed) arc that is drawn when the contacts open

Comment: The load is fully resistive, a heating resistor.

Comment: Note that in many cases an AC application is easier on the contacts than a DC application because the arc upon opening is naturally quenched when the current goes through the zero point of its cycle.